# Hbase ipc.RpcServer responseTooSlow issue and region server goes down

Tags: apache, hadoop, timeout, hbase, nutch

I have configured Hbase 1.2.6 with Hadoop 2.7.4. I have configured Nutch on it. 
Following are two Hbase-site properties

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.rpc.timeout</name>
  <value>1200000</value>
  <description>Changed to 20 minutes</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.client.scanner.timeout.period</name>
  <value>1200000</value>
  <description>Changed to 10 minutes</description>
</property>
```

When I start a job. After some time following warning started and region servers goes down. That's why Job is also failed.

```
2017-12-22 17:39:25,660 WARN  [B.defaultRpcServer.handler=18,queue=0,port=16020] ipc.RpcServer: (responseTooSlow): {"call":"Scan(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ScanRequest)","starttimems":1513946351644,"responsesize":8238,"method":"Scan","param":"scanner_id: 65 number_of_rows: 2147483647 close_scanner: false next_call_seq: 5 client_handles_partials: true client_handles_heartbeats: true track_scan_metrics: false renew: false","processingtimems":14015,"client":"10.11.21.42:36388","queuetimems":0,"class":"HRegionServer","scandetails":"table: use_webpage region: use_webpage,com.blogsky.shayan-pix:http/category/cat-2,1513328565609.09e0aff4d1e1d0e5733825c90f289be5."}
2017-12-22 17:39:37,626 WARN  [B.defaultRpcServer.handler=24,queue=0,port=16020] ipc.RpcServer: (responseTooSlow): {"call":"Scan(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ScanRequest)","starttimems":1513946357681,"responsesize":8654,"method":"Scan","param":"scanner_id: 64 number_of_rows: 2147483647 close_scanner: false next_call_seq: 5 client_handles_partials: true client_handles_heartbeats: true track_scan_metrics: false renew: false","processingtimems":19945,"client":"10.11.21.42:56252","queuetimems":0,"class":"HRegionServer","scandetails":"table: use_webpage region: use_webpage,ir.persianblog.gae6:http/,1509943454203.6992fa37fa94574aa4797b9ae64a296b."}
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice the locality for that region. If the locality is low do a region compaction for that particular region. If that doesn't fix this, run Major Compaction for that table. You can see that the locality for almost all regions becoming 1. This worked for me.